# How do I improve SWT drawing performance?

Tags: java, performance, swt

I was given the task of improving the performance of a stock market charting software that uses SWT's `GC` to draw the charts.  The chart drawing needs to be improved because the charts sometimes are redrawn many times per second, and it consumes lots of processor time.

After googling a little, I found a [blog entry](http://richclientplatform.blogspot.com/2007/08/high-performance-graphics-with-swt.html) that suggests the direct modification of `ImageData` objects instead of using `GC`'s methods, promising great performance gains.

It's an easy task to draw horizontal and vertical straight lines and square shapes using this technique, but when it comes to drawing circles and other irregular shapes there is no easy way.

Does anyone know if there is a library to draw shapes on `ImageData` objects, just like `GC`'s methods do on `Image` objects?

Also, does anyone know another way to improve SWT performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://pub.cosylab.com/CSS/DOC-SWT_Vs._Swing_Performance_Comparison.pdf  I came across this for another question, might be of some help.

Comment: Unfortunately There is no way to get performance when you drawing something using SWT. Each drawing API call requires peer cost that we can't eliminate.

Comment: Consider embedding a web browser and using the HTML Canvas API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of improving the performance of the drawing routines I would concentrate on the drawing logic. Maybe you can just redraw the difference between the old and the new chart? This of course largely depends on how the charts look like and what data they present.

Try to reduce the drawing operations. Do not try to make them faster.

Comment: Example: Render the background (scales, labels, grid) to an image and use that to set up your render area. Then just draw the chart itself on top of that.

Answer (score 7):

Measure the performance of your solution. Where is most time spent? Guessing is not enough. In 90% of the cases, your guesses will be wrong. If you don't know, you can't solve the issue.

SWT itself is not slow. In fact, SWT is just a very thin layer over the respective OS system calls to draw.

One of the problems of SWT is that it's synchronized. To make sure that threading issues cause no problems, there is a global lock. So if you render from several threads at once, this can be a problem.

Or maybe you're not caching resources like colors and fonts properly. These are expensive to create. How many GCs do you create? Do you keep one around or do you create a new one per frame?

But I'm just guessing here. Unless you can prove with a performance monitor "most time is spent in ...", there is no way to help you.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem like a big step (and it is), but the best approach to improve SWT drawing performance for me was to switch to [**OpenGL**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) rendering. I do not imply that you should draw your whole UI with it, but the charts part.
There are many approaches to do that. My choice was to use the [**JOGL library**](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/). There are also some examples around the net, showing how to integrate with SWT.

The downside to this approach is that you have to learn and use a new API which is very different from what one knows from java.
On the other hand, as your scenes are getting more complex, the gains of externalizing the rendering to the GPU are getting bigger. I have experienced FPS gains between 2x and 10x. 
Another good thing is that you don't have to make a deep dive into OpenGL, there are great libraries like [**jMonkeyEngine**](http://jmonkeyengine.org/), hiding much of the underlying complexity.

Comment: Links to JOGL, SWT snippet and jMonkeyEngine are dead